# angular update $scope variable inside loop

Tags: javascript, angularjs, for-loop, scope, iteration

I am trying to update a $scope variable:

ex:

```
$scope.variable_1
$scope.variable_2
...
```

I would like to update it this way:

```
for (i=0; i<2; i++) {    
  $scope.variable_$i = 1;
}
```

What I need is to get access to the "$scope.variable_1" using the index "i" in each iteration.

any suggestion? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I recommend you the use of an array

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use dynamic variable names in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5117127/use-dynamic-variable-names-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In javascript you can access variables by their name :

```
for (i=0; i<2; i++) {    
  $scope['variable_'+i] = 1;
}
```

See : [Dynamically access object property using variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244896/dynamically-access-object-property-using-variable)

Also, accessing properties this way should be avoided if you can use an array instead.

Comment: Correct answer but I don't think one should use *variables* in such cases! May be **Array** is the way to go..

Comment: Totally agree, added note about this